# Modified JUnit xml reporter for jasmine giving RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, junit, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

I am using a modified version of Jasmine JUnit Reports (found here: https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/jasmine-junit-reports) and am getting an error for `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

The reason I modified the report is that I needed the xml reports generated at the `suiteDone` step, not the `jasmineDone` step. So basically I moved all the code from `jasmineDone` into `suiteDone` function, which is now causing the error I am seeing. I am relatively new to js so not exactly sure if some asynchronous issue or something of the sort.

This is the stack trace and related bits of code:

```
- RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at getSuite (C:\Users\AutomationUser\application\admin\adminui\e2e\common-pages\reporter.js:248:26)
        at exportObject.QmetryReporter.self.suiteDone (C:\Users\AutomationUser\application\admin\adminui\e2e\common-pages\reporter.js:312:21)
        at exportObject.QmetryReporter.self.suiteDone (C:\Users\AutomationUser\application\admin\adminui\e2e\common-pages\reporter.js:322:22)
```

`getSuite` function (line 248):

```
function getSuite(suite) {
    __suites[suite.id] = extend(__suites[suite.id] || {}, suite);
    return __suites[suite.id];
}
```

Chunk of `suiteDone` function:

```
self.suiteDone = function (suite) {
    suite = getSuite(suite); // this is line 312 from stacktrace
    if (suite._parent === UNDEFINED) {
        // disabled suite (xdescribe) -- suiteStarted was never called
        self.suiteStarted(suite);
    }
    suite._endTime = new Date();
    currentSuite = suite._parent;
    // below this line is the start of jasmineDone function that I moved into this function
    if (currentSuite) {
        // focused spec (fit) -- suiteDone was never called
        self.suiteDone(fakeFocusedSuite); // this is line 322 from stacktrace
    }
```

The issue seems to only happen when running a larger grouping of test specs. If just running a single test file, I do not get the issue.

Comment: Roughly how many suites (`describe` blocks) are you talking about here in your "large group"? 10's, 100's or 1000's?

Comment: not "large", but larger than 1-2, which like I said I see no issue with. it's 3 specs. 2 of them have a single describe and seem to work fine. the 3rd spec has a describe with nested describe blocks within it, with some of those describes having another describe within...there are several other specs also, just trying to get it working with any set of tests currently..

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this plenty of times. The solution that works for me is to use the [increase-memory-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit) package. Just install it globally and then run `increase-memory-limit` in the root of your project (where your `package.json` is). You should run this command after you have installed all your dependencies and before you start the tests. You will see a bunch of output that looks similar to the following

```
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager' written successfully.
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager.cmd' written successfully.
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack' written successfully.
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli' written successfully.
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli.cmd' written successfully.
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server' written successfully.
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server.cmd' written successfully.
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack.cmd' written successfully.
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/which' written successfully.
'~/app/node_modules/.bin/which.cmd' written successfully.
```

After that, you shouldn't see this error again. My full regression suite is very large and I used to always see the same error when I tried to run the full suite all at once. The above packaged fixed it for me and I haven't had an issue since I started using it.

Comment: I just tried this, but unfortunately am still seeing the issue. I did see the expected logging after running `increase-memory-limit`, so the package is definitely there.